# occasional Windows permission error when calling PowerShell from Java - "running scripts disabled"

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I have a Java program that does a shell call to invoke PowerShell with a script.

My PS script line looks like this:

```
execPS:powershell -command "& 'P:/PSScripts/DownloadSslHtml.ps1' -url 'https://somewebsite.com' -outputFile 'P:/DownloadedData/SomeFile.zip' -PFXPath 'P:/Properties/Config/certfile.pfx' -PFXPassword 'cert_password'"
```

The PS script in question has the following code:

```
param([string]$url = "https://somewebsite.com",
[string]$outputFile = "P:/DownloadedData/someoutput.html",
[string]$PFXPath = "P:/Properties/Config/certfile.pfx",
[string]$PFXPassword = "cert_password")

$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($PFXPath,$PFXPassword,'UserKeySet')
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Certificate $cert -OutFile $outputFile -Verbose
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple.

My Java shell call looks like this:

```
public static String downloadSslWithPshell(String url, String outputFileName, String certName,
                                           String password, boolean waitFor){
    String res = "";
    try {
        ConfigStore configStore = ConfigStore.getInstance();
        String driveLetter = configStore.getDriveFor514();
        String execPS = "powershell -command \"& '" + driveLetter + "PSScripts/DownloadSslHtml.ps1' -url '"
                + url + "' -outputFile '" + outputFileName + "' -PFXPath '"
                + certName + "' -PFXPassword '" + password + "'\"";
        System.out.println("execPS:" + execPS);
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec(execPS);
        if(waitFor) {
            try {
                int resultCode = proc.waitFor();
                if (resultCode == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Script run without errors!");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebManagement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        //from experience we need to put a pause to let it run
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1600);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebManagement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String line;
        InputStream errStream = proc.getErrorStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errStream));
        int countError = 0;
        String strError = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            countError++;
            if(countError<=2){
                strError = strError+line;
            }
        }
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
        if(countError== 0){
            res = "200";
        } else {
            res = strError;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebManagement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here's what happens: 95% of the time the program goes on executing the PowerShell script and it successfully download the file per call.  However about 5% of the time, I get this error message:

> & : File P:\PSScripts\DownloadSslHtml.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

This doesn't make much sense to me.  I have permissions to run PS scripts on my machine and if I run the script manually from PS GUI, it runs fine.  This is an intermittent issue, it seems to only occur occasionally and never consistently.

I'm wondering if this could be an Active Directory issue or a network issue where the system is not able to retrieve the policy?  Just a thought, I really have no idea why I'm getting this error.  Thoughts?  I added " -ExecutionPolicy Bypass" to the PS command arguments so I guess we'll see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is the good call here when you call Powershell.exe so it ignores system poliicy. I am not sure why it would fail 5% of the time though unless on different systems.  Policy is not determined by AD generally and is set to Restricted, by default. You can view the current policy applied to your system by running `Get-ExecutionPolicy`.

Comment: I added the "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass" argument to the Powershell call but I still got the error again today.  It's really intermittent, but when it happens, it seems to happen several times in a row, then it goes away.  Really frustrating.  I went through the event logs today and my PowerShell application log wasn't large enough to hold the error but my System log was and I found something interesting:  "GroupPolicy:  The Group Policy settings for the computer were processed successfully.  New settings from 84 Group Policy objects were detected and applied."  Any chance the GP is causing it?

Comment: A good practice is to run scripts using `-NoProfile` flag to ensure any user/machine profile configurations are skipped. This makes scripts a lot more consistent. If powershell profiles are updated by GP policy this might explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the command:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

You will see there are multiple levels of scopes that can each have their own Execution policy, while I am not sure why your results are so inconsistent, I suspect it may have to do with your CurrentUser policy being undefined. Try running the command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll change the code today and try that and see if it will run without error.